# Simpler way of filling a matrix in each column in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, replication

I want to create a matrix that each column must have a single element replicated n-1 times like my code below.But I want to avoid the all these rep functions in the matrix construction.Is there a simpler way ?

```
p1 = c(1,0.75,0.7,0.65,0.55,0.5,0.3);p1
d = length(p1)
m1 = matrix(c(rep(1,d)   ,rep(0.75,d),rep(0.7,d),
              rep(0.65,d),rep(0.55,d),rep(0.5,d),
              rep(0.3,d)), d, d)

for (i in 1:(nrow(m1)-1)) {
  for (j in (i+1):ncol(m1)) {
    m1[i,j] = 0
  }
}

m1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For constructing the `matrix` a simpler option is

```
m1 <- matrix(p1, d, d, byrow = TRUE)
```

Or use `rep`

```
m1 <- do.call(rbind, rep(list(p1), d))
```

Or use `replicate`

```
m1 <- t(replicate(d, p1))
```

---

The `for` loop can be replaced with `upper.tri` in `base R` to return a logical `vector` and assign those elements to 0

```
m2 <- data.table::copy(m1)
m2[upper.tri(m2, diag = FALSE)] <- 0
```

-testing with OP's output

```
identical(m1, m2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I did mean that.i want to construct from the beginning the matrix without the rep functions

Comment: @Tsiantakis no problem.  It is my mistake.  I should have changed the order of those second block of code to first instead of the one that changes the `for` loop.  Updated